# Customize ServiceLocatorFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have this factory interface

```
class TableManagerFactory {
  TableManager getManager(Table table);
}
```

and current implementation lookups for a custom bean manager implementation or fall to a default one:

```
class TableManagerFactoryImpl implements TableManagerFactory {
  public TableManager getManager(Table table) {
    String beanName = table.getTableCode() + "Manager";
    //  Check for custom bean
    if(!beanFactory.containsBean(beanName)) {
      // Use default bean
      beanName = "defaultTableManager";
    }
    return beanFactory.getBean(beanName);
  }
```

Now I want to use `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean` based on a properties file like:

```
Table1=Table1Manager
Table2=AnotherTableManager
*=defaultTableManager
```

I have 2 problems:

1. In `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean$ServiceLocatorInvocationHandler.tryGetBeanName()`
   because this method just perform a lookup using `Properties.getProperty()`.
2. Table.toString() return a complex string (like `"Table (tableCode) with columns..."`) and should be parsed to extract the `tableCode`

I found a not-so-easy solution based on Spring-AOP

```
 <bean id="RegexServiceLocatorFactoryBeanStrategy_Pointcut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
      <property name="mappedName" value="getProperty" />
      <property name="advice">
        ...
      </advice>
    </bean>
```

---

```
<bean id="TableManagerFactory_ServiceLocatorProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="properties">
    <props>
      <prop key="Table1">Table1Manager</prop>
      <prop key="Table2">AnotherTableManager</prop>
      <prop key="*">defaultTableManager</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

---

```
<bean name="tableManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean">
  <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="application.service.TableManagerFactory" />
    <property name="serviceMappings">
      <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetName" value="TableManagerFactory_ServiceLocatorProperties" />
        <property name="targetClass" value="java.util.Properties" />
        <property name="autodetectInterfaces" value="false" />
        <property name="interfaces"><list /></property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
          <value>RegexServiceLocatorFactoryBeanStrategy_Pointcut</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I wrote a complex advice *a la* `CacheAspectSupport` and one `Interceptor` as:

```
class PropertiesWithRegexInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation m) throws Throwable {
    final String v = (String) m.getArguments()[0];
    final Object r = transformKey(v);
    if(PROCEED != r) {
      m.getArguments()[0] = r;
    }
    return m.proceed();
  }
}
```

I want to make advice configuration easy (and xml-based as much as possible) writing less code as possible.
I'm using Spring 2.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.